# PHP: How to convert an image from URL to Base64?

Tags: php, binary, base64

I want to convert image from its url to base64.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Do you want to create a data url? You need a MIME-Type and some other additional information then (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)). If this is not the case, this would be a simple base64 representation of the image:

```
$b64image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('path/to/image.png'));
```

Relevant docs: [`base64_encode()`-function](http://php.net/base64_encode), [`file_get_contents()`-function](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: what if the url is external, like image from google, how do u handle it?

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña `file_get_contents` will download external urls as well

Answer (score 31):

I got to this question searching for a similar solution, actually, I understood that this was the original question.

I wanted to do the same, but the file was in a remote server, so this is what I did:

```
$url = 'http://yoursite.com/image.jpg';
$image = file_get_contents($url);
if ($image !== false){
    return 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($image);

}
```

So, this code is from a function that returns a string, and you can output the return value inside the src parameter of an img tag in html. I'm using smarty as my templating library. It could go like this:

```
<img src="<string_returned_by_function>">
```

Note the explicit call to:

```
if ($image !== false)
```

This is necessary because file_get_contents can return 0 and be casted to false in some cases, even if the file fetch was successful. Actually in this case it shouldn't happen, but its a good practice when fetching file content.

Answer (score 13):

**Try this:-**

Example One:-

```
<?php 
function base64_encode_image ($filename=string,$filetype=string) {
    if ($filename) {
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
        return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
    }
}
?>

used as so

<style type="text/css">
.logo {
    background: url("<?php echo base64_encode_image ('img/logo.png','png'); ?>") no-repeat right 5px;
}
</style>

or

<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image ('img/logo.png','png'); ?>"/>
```

Example Two:-

```
$path= 'myfolder/myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: Your example two is exactly what I was looking for. +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but check this example http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php#99842

Regards!