# Converting Div into PDF INCLUDING images

Tags: jquery

am referencing this post
[Download a div in a HTML page as pdf using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript)

which basically uses jspdf to make a div into a pdf. I got it to work, but the only problem is I can't get it to add an image as well that would be contained in the div. In other words, I can get the text that's in the div to be a pdf but not the image inside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to use the `html2canvas` or `rasterizeHTML` library. They create a canvas of the HTML page which you can then add to the PDF using `addHTML`

```
$('#cmd').click(function() {
  var options = {};
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.addHTML($("#content"), 15, 15, options, function() {
    pdf.save('pageContent.pdf');
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nerdbiker/f9tsu21k/3/)

Comment: thanks for this! question, why does the image have the data:image/ in there. Would I have to do that for every image? here is what i mean. http://jsfiddle.net/n899opf1/

Comment: It seems that only embedded images (data urls) can be rendered in to the PDF; otherwise the library would have to make HTTP requests for external resources. This is also mentioned in [this example](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/), where it says "You'll need to make your image into a Data URL. Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker"

Comment: You should be able to automate the conversion of images (at least, on the pages you want to be able to convert to PDF) by the use of a bas64 encoding function. Specifics will depend on the code used to implement your site.

Comment: ok that makes sense so each call needs to have the data conversion manual?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "...each call needs to have the data conversion manual?". I was saying you can change the code of your site to automatically change images from links to embedded data urls using a base64 encode function. php has a function base64_encode_image, [see here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25987300/243925).

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant. Converting the image in the div. Thanks Tony!

Comment: I am getting the error payments.js:16109 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document

Comment: @JaberAlNahian - Please post your problem as a new question (linked to this one if you like) and show your code and full error report. It's difficult to properly answer your question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help(It worked for me):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
   downloadImage();
  },1000)
 });
 
 function downloadImage(){
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#divID")).then(canvas => {
  a = document.createElement('a'); 
  document.body.appendChild(a); 
  a.download = "test.png"; 
  a.href =  canvas.toDataURL();
  a.click();
 });
 }  
 </script>
```