# how do I convert image to pdf after display image from database in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to convert image to pdf or print preview which is fetched from database in jquery datatable.

Suppose, I have fetched records from database in a jquery datatable by ajax call and have images in every row. Now, I want to export it in pdf or want to show in print preview, those data are fetched with images in every row.

Comment: Explain your query in brief.

Comment: do you want it using Jquery?

Comment: Yes, I want it using Jquery. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486892/6631280

use `jsPDF.js` plug-in [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nerdbiker/f9tsu21k/3/)

```
<div id="content"><img src="imageURL" ></div>
var options = {}
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML($("#content"), 15, 15, options, function() {
    pdf.save('pageContent.pdf');
});
```

If your image take time to load then 
I suggest use some delay before generate PDF

Comment: Suppose, I have fetched records from database in a jquery datatable by ajax call and have images in every row. Now, I want to export it in pdf or want to show in print preview, those data are fetched with images in every row.

Comment: add button on page to print and it's will generate PDF of everything in target div

Comment: I did it already, but my actual point is, those pictures are show in datatable, after click print button from jquery datatable, pictures are not shown in print preview.